# Is there any way to find server's ports in an android studio project?

Tags: java, android

I am writing code for an android app and I stuck to a point. Is there any possible way to find the ports from a server like nmap on windows or Linux?

For example. If you want to find open ports from a site, using cmd on windows you use the following command

> nmap "site or IP"

and you got the ports. Can I do the same, writing a part of the code in an android app?

ps* this is an example of the code I use to ping a site

```
public void sendPing() {
    try {
        String cmd = "ping site";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        int value = process.waitFor();
        // zero for received packages

        if (value == 0) {
           Log.i(TAG, "Package send");
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting code to ping a site?

Comment: `Is there any way to find server's ports in an android studio project?` ??? You mean open ports on an Android device?

Comment: @greenapps No. I mean the open ports of the server. I must found a way to get a get a result like nmap command (cmd) but programmatically in my project.

Comment: Open ports of which server?

Comment: for example my server. I want a connection to www.myserver.com. If i ping, i get the ip. My question is, if there is any way to see the open port.

Comment: Just try all ports one by one.

Comment: With which cmd command?

Comment: A cmd command on Android? No. Take a client socket and try to connect.